# No intellisense in XAML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I'm no longer getting intellisense in my XAML.  Not too long ago, I changed some settings within VS 2008.  I believe one of them had to do with auto-loading the toolbox.  Secondly, I changed the default XAML editor to the XML editor instead of the designer.  Visual Studio was just acting too slow and this seemed to fix my problems.  Now, I need to do some designer work again and I'm not getting intellisense.  If I go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->XAML, auto list members is greyed out.  Hitting Ctrl-space brings it up for me but I don't want to do this all of the time.  Also, I've noticed I can't even drag a Grid from the tool box onto the XAML.  BTW, I do have resharper installed.  Would that be over-powering some of the VS options?  Any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out myself.  It seems that Resharper was using its own intellisense.  I just simply changed it (Resharper->Options->Environment->Intellisense) to use Visual Studio's instead.  I don't know how it was working before, especially since I haven't messed with this Resharper setting before.

Comment: Please report this to JetBrains so they can fix it: http://www.jetbrains.com/support/support.jsp?pr=ReSharper&ask=Bug%20Report